# Элементы, в зависимости от checkbox, JS

Tags: php, javascript, yii2

Есть форма с checkbox. Тут данные из БД - районы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И есть также форма с checkbox с зонами этих районов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Между собой таблицы связанны по ключу. И вот такой запрос находит зоны, которые соответствуют нужному району.

```
<?= $form->field($objects, 'options_zones_cities')->checkboxList(ArrayHelper::map(\common\models\zones\CityRegionsZone::find()
                    ->where(['city_region_id' => '86'])
                    ->all(),
                    'id','name'))->label('Зоны районов Одессы') ?>
```

Здесь нужно подставлять нужные id - у каждой зоны есть id района

Сами id находятся в option

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне достать id выбранного района, после чего показать зоны, которые им соответствуют(по запросу). Сама форма ajax, то есть id выбрать можно динамически

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь 86,87 - id выбранных элементов.

Вопрос, как с помощью js -
1) достать id
2) передать id в запрос
3) показать зоны, в соответствии к районам (по запросу)